# Multiple queries in a component for Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to createPages and then in the createPage method I'm referencing a specific component for the page

```
createPage({
  path: node.path.alias,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/layouts/custom-page/custom-page.js`),
  context: {
    articleId: node.id,
    authorId: node.relationships.field_author.id
  },
})
```

Within the layout (`custom-page.js`) I'm trying to do 2 queries but it's not working for me. When I test this query in GraphiQL it works fine.

```
export const query = graphql `
    query ($articleId: String!, $authorId: String!) {
      article: nodeArticle(id: {eq: $articleId}) {
        title
        body {
          value
        }
        path {
          alias
        }
      }    
      author: nodePerson(id: {eq: $authorId}) {
        title       
        path {
          alias
        }
      }      
    }
`;
```

Within my component I would then expect to be able to access the data with either `data.author.title` or `data.article.title`.

Is it possible to do this in Gatsby?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is seemed to be bit wrong or some missing in the query.

Query should look like.

```
export const query = graphql `
    query Articles($articleId: String!, $authorId: String!) {
      article: nodeArticle(id: {eq: $articleId}) {
        title
        body {
          value
        }
        path {
          alias
        }
      }    
      author: nodePerson(id: {eq: $authorId}) {
        title       
        path {
          alias
        }
      }      
    }
`;
```

Better to use the package [graphql-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag).

Your query will look like.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const query = gql`
    query Articles($articleId: String!, $authorId: String!) {
      article: nodeArticle(id: {eq: $articleId}) {
        title
        body {
          value
        }
        path {
          alias
        }
      }    
      author: nodePerson(id: {eq: $authorId}) {
        title       
        path {
          alias
        }
      }      
    }
`;
```